# UITableView odd behaviour

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When I tap on my UITableView for the first time after the view loads, I get no output from

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"the clicked index -- %i", indexPath.row);
}
```

On the second tap  - and all subsequent taps - I get the output I would expect from the previous tap (unless tapping on the same row, which of course does not trigger a message). So if I tap rows 2, then 0, then one I get the output:

- Nothing
- 2
- 1

Here the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath;

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    if (_currentTileIndex >= 0 && _currentTileIndex < _timeSlotChumsArrays.count) {

        cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)_timeSlotChumsArrays[_currentTileIndex][indexPath.row];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: put cellForRowAtIndexPath methods code...

Comment: check my answer it will  get slected index of tableview

Comment: You are using the wrong delegate. didDeselect gets called when the cell is deselected. This is a very common mistake, occurs with most people while working with UITableView

Comment: Fast autocompletion, slow brain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong delegate method. -didDeselect gets called when the cell is deselected.

Change

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

use this delegate method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
}
```